# Cant create array with information I need

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an array that I have created with a custom class Students. The information is pulled from a php file and stored in an NSMutableArray after converting the Json format it comes in. For some reason when I try to pull the names of the students after the array has been loaded, they all have the same name. I created an extra simple array that only stores names and that array gets filled each time the student array gets filled but the simple array has the right names I am looking for. I am including my code. Thank you in advance!!

Code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com/students.php"]];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil]; //Or async request
NSError *error=nil;

NSArray *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:0 error:&error];

//Download information and organize on student class
for (int i=0; i<[results count];i++) {
    NSDictionary *DetailDictonary=[results objectAtIndex:i];

    if([studentArray count] == 0){
        NSString *ID = [DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"ID"];
        NSLog(ID);
        NSString *Name = [DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"post_title"];
        NSLog(Name);

        student.studentID =[DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"ID"];

        student.studentName = [DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"post_title"];

        student.grade = [DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"post_content"];
        [studentArray addObject:artist]; // add to array of students
        Students *temp = [studentArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(temp.studentName);
        [tableData addObject:Name]; // simple array used for testing

    }

    else{
        Students *temp = [studentArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(temp.studentName); // verify if name is still the first name added and has not been replaced
        for(int i=0; i <[studentArray count]; i++){
            tempSt = [studentArray objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *tempcompID = tempSt.studentID;
            NSString *tempID = [DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"ID"];
            NSString *Metakey = [DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"meta_key"];
            int ID = [tempID intValue];
            int compID = [tempcompID intValue];
            NSString *metavalue;


            //////////////////////////////////////////////
            /* BOOL isname = false;
             for(int i=0; i <[studentArray count]; i++){
             Students *temp = [studentArray objectAtIndex:i];
             if([temp.studentID isEqualToString:tempID]){
             isname = true;
             }
             }*/
            //////////////////////////////////////////////
            if (compID == ID) {
                NSLog(temp.studentName);
                NSLog(@"student in the array");
                ////////////////////////////
                NSString *Metakey = [DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"meta_key"]; // get key value onto variable
                //NSString *Facebook = [[studentArray objectAtIndex:i] getFacebook];
                NSString *Facebook = tempSt.facebook;
                if([Facebook length] == 0 && [Metakey isEqualToString:@"wpzoom_facebook"]){

                    Facebook = [DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"meta_value"];
                    student.facebook = Facebook;


                }


            }

            else{
                BOOL boolean = false;
                for(int i=0; i <[studentArray count]; i++){
                    Students *temp = [studentArray objectAtIndex:i];
                    if([temp.studentID isEqualToString:tempID]){
                        boolean = true;
                    }
                }
                if(boolean == false){
                    NSLog(temp.studentName);
                    NSLog(@"student in the array");
                    NSLog(@"New student create");
                    NSString *Name = [DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"post_title"];
                    NSLog(Name);
                    NSString *metavalue;
                    NSLog(@"MADE IT HERE");


                    student.studentID =[DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"ID"];

                    student.studentName = [DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"post_title"];

                    student.bio = [DetailDictonary objectForKey:@"post_content"];
                    [studentArray addObject:artist];

                    [tableData addObject:Name];
                    NSLog(@"IM HERE2");
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I am not sure where student object is initialized but I guess you are modifying the same object (student) inside the loop all the time.

Comment: I created and initialized the variable outside, and I am modifying the student after each student information has gone through and student is replaced with new student information

Comment: What is this line?:  [studentArray addObject:artist]; What is artist here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem (aside from code typos) is revealed in your comment:

> I created and initialized the variable outside, and I am modifying the student after each student information has gone through and student is replaced with new student information

You only have one student object which you add repeatedly to the same array, changing it's data each time you pass through the loop. The array ends up containing a sequence of pointers to the same single student object, which only contains data from the last iteration through the loop.

You need to create and initialise a *new* student object on each loop. That student object will get added to the array, then next time through the loop you will make a new student object to hold the next student's data.

Aside from that your code contains errors, repetition and weird logic. Try to reduce the embedded if/else clauses, it makes for poor coding style. It's best to clean that sort of thing up before posting on SO.

Here:

```
[studentArray addObject:artist];
```

I am sure you mean

```
[studentArray addObject:student];
```

I have had to assume that to give you a useful answer...

Comment: this worked! thank you! and yes I used some other code and did not get to change that variable but thanks for noticing!